# Movie Database multiple genres

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I'm trying to build a movie database
Below is a selection from the "Movies" table:

| id | title | genre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Venom | Action, Adventure,Thriller |
| 2 | DeadPool | Action, Comedy |

I heard that I have to use model called a "many-to-many" relationship in the genre column, And it's not a good practice to use comma delimiter when modelling "real world" categorisations.

I want to know why it is not a good practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to know that the right solution is a table with one row per movie and per genre.

Here are some reasons why storing values in a string are a bad idea:

- SQL has poor string processing functionality, so such a query is hard to optimize.
- A column should contain a *single* value.
- It is quite troublesome to validate the values in the column (i.e. you cannot create a foreign key relationship).
- Simple queries -- such as getting a list of the genres or counting the number of genres on a movie -- are more tricky than necessary.
- Genre names cannot contain commas (which might be tricky to enforce as time goes by).
- Removing a value or adding a new value is tricky -- particularly if you want to avoid duplicates.